70s-90s Anime Mecha Movie/Series
I was born in 2000. However as a kid I used to watch a movie or tv show during long car rides to anywhere. However I only remember what seems like nothing useful. I remember the movie starting out with a group of kids what I think is on the moon playing what I thought was baseball. Eventually during the movie the group makes their way down to what could possibly be Earth and save it I think. If anyone can help me find the movie or show I would be very grateful.

Could this be Defenders of Space (AKA Phoenix King) (1984)?

On planet Earth, a galaxy alliance was formed. Together with the good
planets of the solar system, they maintained peace throughout the
universe. Until a new horrible menace threatened the galaxy and
Voltron was needed once more.

The film opens with an attack on a moon base, followed by a scene with some kids playing baseball.





Some of the footage was recycled to make the show Space Thunder Kids but not, as far as I can see, the baseball scene.





